# Boost undefined symbol for architecture arm64

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, arm64, boost-fiber

I'm trying to build a project that contains code with boost 1.65.1 required.
I'm on a Mac OS M1 chipset (arm64)

I downloaded boost using homebrew
`brew install boost`

and the version 1.80.0 was correctly installed.
I complice using gcc g++ (and not clang)
I include the library in my cmake and all the includes are working fine and my IDE is able to find all the function references.

At some part of the code I'm using
`boost::this_fiber::sleep_for` function,

and at the compilation an error is raised by the linker

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_boost::fibers::context::wait_until(std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock, std::chrono::duration<long long, std::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > > const&)", referenced from:
_void boost::this_fiber::sleep_for<long long, std::ratio<1l, 1000000l> >(std::chrono::duration<long long, std::ratio<1l, 1000000l> > const&) in libTest.a
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
```

in my case I find the boost package and linked all boost libraries.
I even tried by hand to add `-lboost_fiber-mt` or `Boost::fiber`  and I always end up with the same error.

Do you have any idea why the symbol is undefined ? The same code works perfectly on a ubuntu x86_64.

I tried include the libraries by hand in the make and symbols is always undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not *quite* the answer you're looking for unfortunately, but I've had the same experience with a `brew` install, but have had success building the boost libraries myself, downloading from [here](https://www.boost.org/users/download/) and following installation instructions [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/tools/build/doc/html/index.html). Hope this is helpful!

Comment: thanks @dogs for the answer.
Did you install manually the exact same version install by boost, or another specific version ?

Comment: I installed version 1.80.0, which was the latest at the time of install (and the same version as `brew` had). I believe `brew` is up to 1.81.0 now though? either way I think installing the latest version from the boost website should work!